# Substring and reverse index with awk

Tags: bash, shell, indexing, awk, substring

I have a path that I retrieve with the **pwd** command, I have to modify that path runtime in my shell script. For istance let's say I have */var/www/cgi-script*, I have to modify it in */var/www/etc*. What I am trying to do is retrieve the last index of *"/"*, take a substring and then add *etc*. I tryed with **awk** several times but I can't seem to find a solution. Is there a way to use a reverse index?

```
path=`pwd`;
char="/"
pathindex=`awk -v a="$path" -v b="$char" 'BEGIN { print index(a,b)}'`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [dirname](http://ss64.com/bash/dirname.html):

```
$ pwd
/var/www/cgi-script
$ echo $PWD
/var/www/cgi-script
$ echo `dirname $PWD`/etc
/var/www/etc
```

Answer (score 3):

@AndersLindahl has the right answer. To do this in awk:

```
newpath=$(awk -F $char -v OFS=$char '{$NF="etc"; print}' <<< "$path")
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a little different, I'm already in the code - it's too late to do a new FS.  I have a persons name which has an unknown number of words, but the last word is their surname and needs to be surrounded by "/"

```
  a=split(prsn,x," ")  # Split into 'x' based on a space, 'a'=number of words
  prsn=""              # reset variable to null
  for (j=1;j<a;j++) {  # loop through and concatenate all but the last word
                     prsn=sprintf("%s %s",prsn,x[j])
                    }
   prsn=substr(prsn,2) # we got an extra space in there at the beginning - lose it
   prsn=sprintf("%s /%s/",prsn,x[a])  # format the final name
   print "1 NAME " prsn # print it
```

Comment: What do you mean by "too late to do a new FS"?